# Bitwise enum (flags) query using MongoDB's official C# driver

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bitwise-operators

When I try to run a LINQ query of the form:

```cs
MongoCollection<MyEntity> collection;

collection.AsQueryable().Where(entity =>
    (entity.Flags & MyFlags.AFlag) != MyFlags.None);
```

I get an `ArgumentException` with the message `Unsupported where clause: ((Int32)((Int32)entity.Flags & 4) != 0).`

**Is this a known bug/feature?**

**Is there any workaround?**

From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) it seems like MongoDB has a bitwise update, but not a bitwise query.

For comparison, the same query runs smoothly above Redis using ServiceStack as a client.

I did find these two links ([link1](http://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/mongodb-bitwise-filtering-faster-status-querying-performance/), [link2](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/12247pc2d6/bitwise-operations-while-querying)) which suggest using JavaScript, however, that would make the implementation of the service layer very dependant on the DB technology.

Comment: maybe you can try use linq to object to query:
collection.AsQueryable().ToList().Where(entity =>
    (entity.Flags & MyFlags.AFlag) != MyFlags.None);

Comment: That would deserialize all the objects into memory. I can use that after other filters though (assuming they reduce the records enough).

Comment: @Tim.Tang This works with my queries, since I had other conditions I could filter with beforehand. Also noticed that GroupBy() fails and needs to be move to after .ToList(). Post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution has two parts.
I made a serializer for Enum flags that stores all the values in a list of strings.
I made an extension method for Linq to "inject" the mongo query i need.

```
public static IQueryable<TItem> HasFlags<TItem, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<TItem> items,
    Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>> itemPropertyExpression,
    params Enum[] enumFlags)
{
    var enumFlagNames = enumFlags.Select(enumFlag => (BsonValue)enumFlag.ToString());
    return items.Where(item => Query.In(ExtendedObject.GetPropertyName(itemPropertyExpression), enumFlagNames).Inject());
}
```

That way, its both readable and i don't need to deserialize all the objects into memory.

P.S: The GetPropertyName method is just a type safe way to get the property name:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TClass, TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> entityPropertyExpression)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)entityPropertyExpression.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll need a much more robust `GetPropertyName` if you want to handle dot notation, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with MongoDB v 3.2 you can use [bitsAllSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllSet/) or [bitsAnySet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAnySet/) depending on what are you searching for.

So, with C# MongoDB Driver:

```
//Check single Flag as OP
collection.Find(Builders<MyEntity>.Filter.BitsAllSet(myEntity => myEntity.Flags, (long) MyFlags.AFlag));

//Check all multiple Flags
collection.Find(Builders<MyEntity>.Filter.BitsAllSet(myEntity => myEntity.Flags, (long) MyFlags.AFlag | MyFlags.BFlag));

//Check any multiple Flag
collection.Find(Builders<MyEntity>.Filter.BitsAnySet(myEntity => myEntity.Flags, (long) MyFlags.AFlag | MyFlags.BFlag));
```

**Note**: There's an [open issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24749) to use indexes on Bitwise operations. On MongoDB 4.2 they still don't use them, so be aware if you plan on using them massively (we were and we had to refactor everything afterwards).